# Определить пункт выдачи с самым большим или самым маленьким кол-вом читателей

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, запрос

Используется *MS Sql Server 2014*:

```
select 
  выдача.код_пункта
 ,тип
 ,[Пункт Выдачи].факультет
 ,count(distinct код_билета) as [Количество читателей]
from
  dbo.Выдача 
inner join
  dbo.[Пункт Выдачи] 
on 
  dbo.Выдача.код_пункта = dbo.[Пункт Выдачи].код_пункта
where 
  дата_возврата > getdate()
group by 
  выдача.код_пункта
 ,тип
 ,[Пункт Выдачи].факультет
```

Пока только нашел количество читателей для каждого пункта. Теперь среди них нужно выбрать с мин. или макс. количеством.

Comment: [MIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179916(v=sql.120).aspx), [MAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187751(v%3Dsql.120).aspx)? Не, не слышал.

Comment: min вместе с count нельзя использовать

Comment: а вместо? )) и то и то -- аггрегирующая функция, group by вы сделали.

Answer (score 0):

Например, для максимального значения (для минимального нужен MIN вместо MAX):

```
SELECT  код_пункта
    ,тип
    ,факультет
    ,MAX([Количество читателей]) AS [Максимальное количество]
FROM (
    select выдача.код_пункта
        ,тип
        ,[Пункт Выдачи].факультет
        ,count(distinct код_билета) as [Количество читателей]
    from dbo.Выдача 
        inner join dbo.[Пункт Выдачи] on dbo.Выдача.код_пункта = dbo.[Пункт Выдачи].код_пункта
    where дата_возврата > getdate()
    group by выдача.код_пункта
    ,тип
    ,[Пункт Выдачи].факультет
) t
GROUP BY код_пункта
    ,тип
    ,факультет
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select выдача.код_пункта, тип, [Пункт Выдачи].факультет, 
  count(distinct код_билета) as [Количество читателей]
from dbo.Выдача 
inner join dbo.[Пункт Выдачи] on 
  dbo.Выдача.код_пункта = dbo.[Пункт Выдачи].код_пункта
where 
  дата_возврата > getdate()
group by выдача.код_пункта, тип, [Пункт Выдачи].факультет
ORDER BY [Количество читателей] DESC
```

Первая строка - с максимальным, последняя - с минимальным :-)
К вашему запросу добавлена только последняя строка (order by ... )